# Understanding WSO2 Process Center

Tags: wso2

How to integrate WSO2 Process center with other WSO2 applications?
Is there any way to do so? Kindly share the documentation regarding this if available.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Process Center is a new product which will be released in 2016 Q2. So at the moment there are no official documentation. WSO2 PC will be a center for business process and it will tightly integrate WSO2 Business Process Server (WSO2 BPS) and WSO2 Rules Server (WSO2 BRS). On the hand Process Related Stats can be integrated to WSO2 Data Analytic Server (WSO2 DAS) where as sparks queries will be deployed in the WSO2 DAS.

You can download a milestone pack from WSO2 official web site [1]

[1] http://wso2.com/products/process-center/

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Process Center provides a complete, end-to-end solution for business process management. WSO2 PC forms the central component of WSO2’s BPM platform by providing centralized storage, governance, process monitoring/analytics, and process improvement support.

It enables users to discover relevant processes and initiate automated processes, domain experts to design processes using different formats as an example define processes in text, pdf, document, etc.

And also provide process owners to monitor existing processes, analyze process history, and identify possibilities of optimization utilizing Data Analytics Server. WSO2 PC offers a Process Explorer app as well as a Process Designer app to add/create new processes.

Please see this videos during recent WSO2Cons

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWIAeNR59YE&feature=youtu.be

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1FcL1yThaM